# Sometimes web pages doesn't get loaded

Tags: networking, internet, connection, airport, fiber

I've a fiber connection of 50 Mb/s at my home. The fiber connection is hooked up to the router/modem box of my ISP. But I've disabled the ISP's router/modem's WLAN function through it's dedicated button to disable WLAN and I'm distributing my wireless connection through the latest generation [AirPort Extreme](http://www.apple.com/airport-extreme/) by Apple since I enjoy the advantages of the AirPort Extreme.

When my fiber got first connected, everything was working fine with this exact setup in place. But now, occasionally, some web pages won't get loaded. Basically Safari gives the "Web page couldn't be found." message for some time, like for couple of minutes, and then when I hit refresh, it gets loaded as usual. Or rather than not getting loaded, the page gets loaded as broken, just text, no styling, and it gets correct after I hit refresh after some time.

And also, this problem is not related to one of my devices as well. When it occurs, it happens on all of my devices that are connected to my network.

I talked with my ISP several times and every time they've responded that my connection was fine; that there was no single problem with it.

Any suggestions? What is the source of the problem exactly?

Comment: This is typically a name server problem (thought more precise error message info would help narrow in on that a bit).

Comment: Not quite sure at the moment but it was probably a message saying "Safari can't open the page "..." because Safari can't find the server "..."". I'll update it if the problem happens again.

Comment: It just happened and it's that error message. After one try though, the site got loaded but it got loaded broken.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Can you please elaborate on the name server problem

Comment: I don't know what all the scenarios are, but often a name server will quit responding or will be sluggish.  You will notice that requests are sluggish with frequent "not found" or "not responding" errors or missing components that sometimes clear up on retry.  Switching name servers makes the problem go away.  I think sometimes you did not load the correct name server when connecting, and other times the default name server is hosed.

Comment: (Note that often your router will provide DNS function via a pass-through IP address, so the problem can be with what the router is using for DNS, or simply something hosed within the router.)

Comment: After digging around in some websites about my ISP, I saw that this is an issue about my ISP unfortunately which they're totally ignoring at the moment. :(

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what the problem is from information given, but I solved a similar issue by changing my DNS server. You might want to try following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)(google) to use google DNS.

Comment: Yeah, changing to use a different (non-default) DNS will likely fix it.